# Add Url parameters to all Restkit request

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit-0.20

Is they a way to add some url parameters (like http://api.example.com/v3/object?data=123&info=test) to all restkit request witouth adding them manually to all

```
getObjectsAtPath:parameters:success:failure:
getObjectsAtPathForRouteNamed:object:parameters:success:failure:
...
```

each request should add the info parameter.

I've actually a way to do it, using Method Swizzling. Is they a way to do it directly with RestKit?

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of ways to do this:

you can either subclass the methods of RKObjectManager to something like this:

```
-(void)addedParamToGetObjectsAtPath:(NSString*)path parameters:(NSDictionary*)parameters success:(success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult)successBlock failure::^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error){

NSMutableDictionary* newParams = [NSMutableDictionary new];
if(parameters){
       [newParams addEntriesFromDictionary:parameters];
}
newParams[@"info"]=test;
getObjectsAtPath:(NSString*)path parameters:(NSDictionary*)parameters success:(success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult){
// Deal with the success here
successBlock(operation, mappingResult);
} failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
//Deal with the error here
errorBlock(operation, error);
}];
```

Or tell Restkit to use a different RequestOperationClass

```
//When configuring RestKit
RKObjectManager *objectManager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:BASE_URL]];
//Some more configuration
//....
[objectManager registerRequestOperationClass:[YourObjectRequestOperation class]];
```

And define a subclass of RKObjectRequestOperation, YourObjectRequestOperation

```
#import "FBObjectRequestOperation.h"

@interface RKHTTPRequestOperation ()
@property (nonatomic, strong, readwrite) NSMutableURLRequest* request;
@end

@implementation FBObjectRequestOperation


- (id)initWithHTTPRequestOperation:(RKHTTPRequestOperation *)requestOperation responseDescriptors:(NSArray *)responseDescriptors
{
NSParameterAssert(requestOperation);
NSParameterAssert(responseDescriptors);

//your method to change the requestOperation

RKHTTPRequestOperation* myRequestOperation = [YourObjectRequestOperation addParametersToRequest:requestOperation];

self = [super initWithHTTPRequestOperation:myRequestOperation responseDescriptors:responseDescriptors];
if (self) {
 //Change headers or any other thing that you need
}

return self;
```

}

To actually change the requestOperation you will need to get the url from the request and and add there the new parameters. That will happen in this part `RKHTTPRequestOperation* myRequestOperation = [YourObjectRequestOperation addParametersToRequest:requestOperation];` and I am living up to you to complete the code.

This should work for any request you are doing with the object manager.
This technique is also very helpful is you need to calculate headers dynamically for each request.